# Converting AC to DC 1,000,000 volts

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier, power

I'm trying to create an electric field that has 1,000,000 volts of dc current. So far my plan is to take a 12v dc battery, get a High Voltage Pulse Generator [link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07QNQPQM5) and make 1,000,000 ac volts, and then connect it to a rectifier to make 1,000,000 volts DC. My problem is, I can't find a reliable rectifier that can take more the 1,000V, so if someone could help find a powerful rectifier, it would be great. I know my plan is a little weird so if anyone else knows a different way to make 1,000,000 DC volts from a 12v battery, it would be great!

I don't care what the amperage is

Comment: Tesla did this stuff over 120 years ago with a LOT less to work with. I know for a fact that million-volt cathode "ray" tubes were being built more than 100 years ago. And those make up a pretty good diode. Not even hard to do, if you are okay with glass-blowing. (I've done it, though not for that voltage difference.) You can always see about the possibility to chaining up lots of semiconductor diodes, I suppose. (But make sure you bury them in specialized oils designed for the purpose. You don't want arcing.)

Comment: The highest-voltage single-junction solid-state rectifiers currently available are silicon carbide schottky diodes that can withstand a bit over 3 kV. You might be able to rectify a megavolt with a mercury arc rectifier. I would recommend rather just using an electrostatic generator, like a van de Graaf generator or a Wimshurst machine. But more importantly than all that, I would really like to know what your purpose of making something like this is!

Comment: would having multiple rectifiers in series work?

Comment: @AakarshTathachar To a limited extent, depending on how well you can balance the voltage across each one. Why *do* you want to do this, anyway? This isn't even remotely a practical project.

Comment: I am trying to create a powerful electric field and see how water and water reactions behave in it. I looked into making a van de graaff generator and I tried making it but it just took too much time and effort so I'm looking for a simpler way.

Comment: @AakarshTathachar I'm pretty confident in saying there is no simpler way to produce a megavolt than a van de Graaff generator.

Comment: @AakarshTathachar Start [here](https://www.diyphysics.com/2012/02/09/d-i-y-250-kv-high-voltage-dc-power-supply-with-neat-trick-for-switching-polarity/). This shows you how to approach it. If you need further help, I think you should feel free to write to the Prutchi's. I believe they may be willing to help. Especially if you include them in a few details you are thinking about as a project. I'll be creating a laboratory here to focus on creating tools for physics investigations (starting mid to late next year) and I'm sure I'll be writing them, too. Best wishes.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, but lastly would something like this work? https://www.amazon.com/1000000v-Voltage-Generator-Transformer-Converter/dp/B099JFSJRQ

Comment: @AakarshTathachar *"There are 0 customer reviews and 1 customer rating."* Are you serious about an actual study regarding water? Or do you just want a toy to play with? If this is just a matter of having fun (nothing wrong with that) then feel free to get the Amazon units. If they don't work, not much time or money is lost and you move on to something else. But there is no way I'd imagine those to be of much serious purpose. They are toys. And if you are lucky enough that they survive a few uses, be glad for that much. How would you plan on measuring the voltage, by the way?

Comment: Looks like making 1,000,000 volts seem to hard, is there a simpler way of making 500,000 volts or less? as for measuring voltage, I have a multimeter

Comment: @AakarshTathachar I'm going to assume you are very young. (I was too, at some point.) If you want to take this on, then you will have to have strong motivations. Where those come from? I don't know. I had them. I was very very poor and could not afford much. Not even a multimeter. I also had no friends who could help. No family, either. So I had to make everything: Power supply. Multimeter. Geiger counter. AM radio receiver. Etc. All from scratch. And learn by myself by going to libraries and spend entire days there. My point? You can do "hard" things, if you set your mind to it.

Comment: @AakarshTathachar What exactly do you want to observe with water? What effects can you predict without doing the experiments? (Study existing research topics with as wide and deep a scope as you can afford to do.) This process will help you work out what the minimum goals might be (how small of an effect are you willing to accept?) You learn what you need to control, what to build, etc. Once you have that much in hand, list out your "knowable unknowns" and uncontrollable variables and see if those swamp out the effect itself. You should already know what to expect before you start.

Comment: @AakarshTathachar If this is to explore new territory -- you've studied existing knowledge and want to find some new effect -- then you must fully and completely grasp the current knowledge on the topic, first. This is much harder, these days, because there is so much already done before. So far far more to study. Once you have those, you can design experiments that can measure all those effects and look for ***residuals*** that are as yet unexplained and yet too large given the accuracy of your measuring systems to be explained by experimental error. Then you have something!

Comment: _”1,000,000 volts of dc current”_ Voltage isn’t current. I would recommend you to stay far away from anything high voltage.

Answer (score 7):

> if anyone else knows a different way to make 1,000,000 DC volts from a 12v battery

Run the motor of a van de Graaff generator from a 12 volt battery. That way, you won't need a 1,000,000 volt rectifier.

Comment: It's reliable, safe, works well, and there are lots of 'how to build' plans on the interwebs if you want to DIY it.

Comment: At 3kV/mm breakdown voltage 300kV requires a torroidal electrode about 1m apart. this product is not even close. Although for an impulse <1us the distance can be reduced but requires a low capacitance to limit current, C= Ic dt/dV = 0.1us/1e6V= 1A per pF limited by V/DCR of secondary.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 A van de Graaff generator is not even close? I have seen a van de Graaff generator that generates up to 10 million volts depending upon humidity.

Answer (score 6):

You can also get 1,000,000 V from 12 V batteries by connecting 83,334 in series.

Comment: This should be possible for relatively cheap, if you buy A23 batteries in bulk. Note that "relatively cheap" still means "tens of thousands of USD".

Comment: I did wire up 60 AA batteries to create a 90 VDC supply that I used to then generate 1600 VDC for a geiger counter I designed and built (in 1971.) Bought the geiger tube directly from the physicist who'd designed it, too!! Back in the day, you could often just write the designer. Or, maybe I was too dumb back then and didn't know any better. ;) Of course, I don't think I'd have taken on anything more than a few hundred series batteries. It was a lot of work, already.

Comment: Alternatively, 9V PP3 batteries can be plugged together like Lego :)

Comment: @IanBland Yeah. I tried that. They didn't last that long with my geiger counter, though. Switched over to AA. That lasted long enough for good work. Used two AA modules, each of 45 V.